# External command error: /usr/local/bin/snmpget: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmp.so.20: cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, snmp, nagios, net-snmp

I'm able to do a `snmpget`/`snmpwalk` and `check_snmp` through command line. 
But, when I do it through Nagios (creating a host & services entry in the config files), I see this error in the "Status Information" of the services under specific host:

> External command error: /usr/local/bin/snmpget: error while loading
>   shared libraries: libnetsnmp.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory
>
> OS: SLES 11

Answer (score 10):

The below procedure is helpful, if `libnetsnmp.so.XX`  is in your system.

First search for library libnetsnmp.so.XX

```
sudo find / -name libnetsnmp.so*
```

So you will get output like below

```
/usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.30
/usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.15
/usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.15.1.2
/usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so.30
/usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so
/usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so.30.0.2
/usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so.20
...
```

Now link that `libnetsnmp.so.XX` to `/usr/lib/`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so.XX /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.XX
```

Comment: The above solution didn't work for me. `cp /usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so.XX /usr/lib` worked

Answer (score 0):

The program misses a library.
You can find a list of libraries the program needs using `ldd`:

```
$ ldd /usr/local/bin/snmpget
```

You will see `not found` near the libraries that are missing.

When you where located libraries that `snmget` needs, and that is a special location (not `/usr/lib` and so on), you can added to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
 $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/path-to/lib ldd /usr/local/bin/snmpget
```

Comment: ldd /usr/local/bin/snmpget
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc33ff000)
 libnetsnmp.so.20 => /usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so.20 (0x00007fefca658000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fefca402000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fefca0a4000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fefca929000)

Comment: There ain't any missing lib !

Comment: I have already set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/local/lib, where all the libraries are.
Still not working !

Comment: may be `libnetsnmp.so.20` is a 32bit library. please check it using `file` command. just run `file /path/to/lib.so`

Comment: no, when ldd finds all dependency, LD_LIBRARY_PATH will not help you of course.

Comment: This is what I get:
/usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so.20.0.2: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped

It is a 64bit lib only

Comment: can you please install `ltrace` and run `ltrace /usr/local/bin/snmpget` and see what happens?

Comment: This is what I get at the end... 

fwrite("  -C APPOPTS\t\tSet various applic"..., 1, 59, 0x7f5d6d51d860  -C APPOPTS  Set various application specific behaviours:
)                           = 59
fwrite("\t\t\t  f:  do not fix errors and r"..., 1, 49, 0x7f5d6d51d860     f:  do not fix errors and retry the request
)                          = 49
exit(1 <unfinished ...>
+++ exited (status 1) +++

Answer (score 0):

Even if you add the library path to the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, your programe cann't figure out the location of desired libraries as they are not yet exported.  you can think of it as you draw a map to trace something, and forget to put the map into your bag, so when you begin searching, you don't know where the goddamn thing is located. The clue is to export them (locations). How ? simply, using the keyword export before any changes of the environment variable, like :
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/libraries/location/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

and that's it ;-)

Cheers